# What to do with Zend_Rest_Client_Result?

Tags: zend-framework, rest

I'm trying to do searches with the API from last.fm with Zend_Rest_Client.

What am I to do with the response? How do I get the values from the response?

```
object(Zend_Rest_Client_Result)[226]
  protected '_sxml' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[228]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array
          'status' => string 'ok' (length=2)
      public 'results' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[229]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array
              ...
          public 'trackmatches' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[230]
              ...
  protected '_errstr' => null
```

How do I loop over trackmatches? Everything I try returns null.

Comment: Did you try `echo $result`, `foreach($result as $stuff) echo $stuff;` or `echo $result->trackmatches`?

Comment: Yes, all of them returns null. Which I gather is the return from the magic getter. Even with toValue() everything is null.

Comment: think you have to do: $result = $object->getIterator(); than you are able to loop through your result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to be able to do it with Zend. Looks like a useless class like Zend_Http. I had to use the gool 'ol SPL:

```
    $url = $this->host . '?method=track.search';
    $url .= '&api_key=' . $this->apikey;
    $url .= '&track=' . urlencode($value);

    try {
        $xmlstr = file_get_contents($url);
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
        //var_dump($xml->results->trackmatches);
        return $xml->results->trackmatches;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '<h4>url = ' . $url . '</h4>';
        var_dump($e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = $object->getIterator();
foreach($result as $result) {
   ...
}
```

Above code will do the magic.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep dereferencing until you get to something that isn't a SimpleXMLElement object.  Trying to print a SimpleXMLElement object doesn't work.

```
$results = $object->getIterator();
foreach($results->results->trackmatches as $t) {
    echo $t->sometagname;
}
```